# Поиск элемента, если в class содержится несколько слов, разделенных пробелами. Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium

Пробую получить веб-элемент наименования товара со страницы: https://market.yande...LF560V&srnum=53. Пробовал получать его с помощью `xPath` и `cssSelector`. Однако ничего не выходит. Веб-элемент не находится. Прикрепил изображение: `webElement`.

Пробовал так:

```
webElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
       "//h1[contains(@class, 'title.title_size_32.title_changeable_yes')]"));
```

Или так

```
webElem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
          "h1.title.title_size_32.title_changeable_yes"));
```

Или даже так:

```
webElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "//div[@class='headline__header']/h1"));
```

Но в результате элемент не находится.

Сам селектор указывает на эту строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<h1 class="title title_size_32   title_changeable_yes" 
     title="LG 32LF560V">LG 32LF560V</h1>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, получить этот элемент. Мне нужно получить именно через `class`, не касаясь ни `title`, ни текста, содержащегося в этом элементе. Просто нужно найти элемент, касаясь только `class="title title_size_32   title_changeable_yes"`.

Comment: String clazzName = "title title_size_32   title_changeable_yes" ;driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//h1[contains(@class,"+clazzName+")]")). Если такой не сработает, то надо делать такой xpath : contains(@class,"title") and contains(@class,"title_size_32") и так далее все классы через and перечислять

Answer (score 0):

Решить эту проблему можно следующими способами:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[@class='class1 class2']"));
```

или

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@class,'class1 class2')]"));
```

или

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".class1.class2"));
```